# The "App\Security\UserAuthenticator::getUser()"method must return a UserInterface. You returned "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse"

Tags: symfony

im trying to make a login method with symfony 4 , i have create this method  public function

```
getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['username' => $credentials['username']]);

        if (!$user) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_login'));
        }

        return $user;
    }
```

when i put a false user it display to me this error:

```
The "App\Security\UserAuthenticator::getUser()" method must return a UserInterface. You returned "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse".
```

Comment: You should throw an exception instead, this is what [make:user](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-user) does. Then in your controller you can catch that perticular exception and redirect..

Comment: @Bossman Throwing a user not found exception is correct however controllers are not involved in the authentication process.  It's up to the rest of the authentication system to catch.  More importantly the UserProvider should be making these kind of database calls.  I think the poster might be mixing some of the newer security stuff with the older 4.4 stuff.

Comment: @Cerad, yeah my mistake. yahya, In your login method/route (SecurityController) it gets any errors thrown so it can display in your template.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using a simple `FormAuthenticator` extending `AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator` (which is deprecated for symfony 5.3+ with the new authenticator system).

`getUser()` should only return an user or throw an exception so you should remove your redirect with:

```
public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['username' => $credentials['username']]);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException('User not found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }
```

*(You may want to use a less descriptive exception for security reason)*.

If I remember how it looked like in 4.4, your login method in your controller should look like:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request\AuthenticationUtils;

/**
 * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
 */
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
{
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('security/login.html.twig',
        [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
        ]
    );
}
```